Pgbouncer: Can pgbouncer take reserve_pool_timeout in milliseconds?
Is it possible to specify pgbouncer reserve_pool_timeout in milliseconds, I have tried specifying it with '500 ms' but throwing an error and then tried specifying 0.5, this time no error  but unable to find out it's really working or just disabled the timeout but reserve_pool are being utilised.

The internal data type used is usec_t, which is time in microseconds. So fractional seconds will work.
Instead of using a reserve pool, why don't you increase the normal pool size? That pool should be sized so that the database is under load, but not overloaded, when all connections are in use. In that case, it would be detrimental to allow additional connections via a reserve pool.

Thanks for the answer . I have been thinking reserve_pool is useless just like way you said. But once after our implementation we have realised that our connections are bursty with a very short period of time taking all connections with query exec time of less than 20ms. Then it's idle for the rest of time.

Now the pgbouncer queue wait time is in microseconds, so if we can have 100ms of acceptable waiting time 1 server connection will be able to service nearly 5 client connections instead of opening another 5 server connections.  Our situation is even with transaction mode the pooling or multiplexing is not really working because of our kind of workload.
